# To change a language automatically, should you use the Keyboard Language or the Location value?

Tags: language-agnostic

To change a language automatically, should you use the Keyboard Language or the Location value?

Comment: I'm using US keyboard to type asian characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm from Spain... usually I have my keyboard arranged in Spanish Traditional Sorting (AKA Spanish International), but sometimes I change it to en_us for some tasks... anyway, the locale of my operating system is always in Spanish, even if some applications are in English (because they don't have an Spanish translation or whatever).

The point is, if a user has his OS and environment set to a particular language, usually that's his preferred language. That's not always true for the keyboard, as some sortings are better for some tasks (like, your language sorting for writing in your language, en_us for programming or using legacy software, and so on...).

Hopefully all this makes clear the best choice for your question ;).

Answer (score 1):

In my situation I am in Japan, but uses english as the working language. So, I prefer language to be  English. It depends on the situation. But, usually keyboard language depict the working language of the user. Hence, I recommend changing the language to keyboard language.

Comment: Do you use an English keyboard and your environment is kept in Japanese? If that is so... do you prefer the applications to be in English, even if you have your environment and OS in Japanese? Or do you prefer all in English (making the choice by keyboard or location irrelevant)?

Comment: At home I have everything in English. So, irrelevant of location I prefer application language to be English. But, web sites including Google shows up in Japanese.

At work, I have OS and Keyboard in Japanese. And the choice of language differ according to the situation. So, I believe it's fair enough that the language be in Japanese.

Comment: The other case is when my OS is Japanese and change the keyboard language to English. In that case I would prefer the language to be English.

Comment: I don't understand location as the physical location, that I agree is mostly irrelevant. I think the question asks about the configured Locale, that is the OS or environment language setting. If you have everything showing in Japanese, do you prefer a single application to pop in English because of your keyboard setting? Doesn't make more sense, then, to switch all to English? I'm just curious, we are of different cultures so usage trends may be different.

Comment: I absolutely agree with the point that, application language should be irrelevant from physical location.Problem is whether it should be dependent on OS(Locale) or Keyboard language(in the sense keyboard is language is set from Region and Language settings). In this situation if the keyboard language is English I prefer application to be English.

Comment: As you said it depends on our culture. Your locale is Spanish(First Language) and you prefer the language to be Spanish(OS Language) to be the application language even though keyboard is English(Second Language). But my OS is Japanese(Say Third Language), if my keyboard language is English(Say Second Language) I prefer the application language. Finally, I suggest that automated language change should be decided on the user base and should be implemented according tot them.